# Error while parsing url contains json objects

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have tried that code for parsing url contain JSON objects but it there is an error at the line :`private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivitiesActivity.this);`

this ActivitiesActivity to show the list from the json objects .

This is the code:

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivitiesActivity.this);
InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = ""; 

protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
    progressDialog.show();
    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

    String url_select = "http://yoururlhere.com";

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {
        // Set up HTTP post

        // HttpClient is more then less deprecated. Need to change to URLConnection
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        // Read content & Log
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e1.toString());
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
        Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
        Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
        e3.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e4) {
        Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
        e4.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Convert response to string using String Builder
    try {
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        inputStream.close();
        result = sBuilder.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("StringBuilding & BufferedReader", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
} // protected Void doInBackground(String... params)


protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

    //parse JSON data
    try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = jObject.getString("Title");
            String tab1_text = jObject.getString("Date");
            //int active = jObject.getInt("active");


        } // End Loop

        this.progressDialog.dismiss();

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

    } // catch (JSONException e)


} // protected void onPostExecute(Void v)

} //class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
```

Comment: what is your activity name? and is your asynctask an inner class of the activity?

Comment: @Raghunandan no the asynctask not an inner class, it normal one.

Comment: @user2870902 then how can you get the activity context there. what is meant was is asynctask in a different .java file or is it inside activity class

Comment: @Brontok the error is in the code itself i cant run it. the error :     No enclosing instance of the type ActivitiesActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: @Raghunandan yes it is different .java

Comment: @user2870902 check my answer. pass the context and use the same to initialize progress dialog

Answer (score 1):

From your comments "no the asynctask not an inner class".

If your asynctask is not a inner class you need to pass the activity context to the constructor of Asynctask.

```
 new MyAsyncTask(YourActivityName.this).execute(params);
```

Then in AsyncTask have the constructor and initialize `progressDialog`

```
 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
 public MyAsyncTask(Context context)
 {
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
 }
```

Edit: add @Override Annotation  and call `super.onPreExecute()` and `super.onPostExecute(param)`

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void V) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(v);
            // rest of the code
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
           // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: where can i add this new MyAsyncTask(YourActivityName.this).execute(params); ?

Comment: @user2870902 add that in your activity class from where you invoke the asynctask and params is what you pass to doinbackground

Answer (score 0):

Update your AsyncTask like this

```
 class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    Context context;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = ""; 


    public MyAsyncTask(Context context)
         {
            this.context=context;
         }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Downloading your data...");
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                MyAsyncTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Pass **context** to the constructor of your AsyncTask(MyAsyncTask ) and Use this context wherever you need to access Methods of the Calling Activity.